# Field stored with htmlentities in PostgreSQL, how do I search (sql select) for special characters, say, < without doing a &lt; search?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a situation where user can post codes in a textbox and I store it in a table where all special characters are stored as htmlentities.

How do I search within the table for the character '<' without search for its html entities equivalent? Does postgresql have a built in function for this?

Thank you for your time

Comment: hmm, wouldn't searching for the character '<' itself within a html text exclude automatically all html entitles?

Comment: @didierc Yes but then I have to output it as html to search for it, so I would be using a serverside language to search for it no? I want the database to search for it instead?

Comment: If your html is stored as escaped text, you will have a hard time looking for tags in there, but if it is stored as valid html, then the special characters which should be escaped (ie, those not part of a tag or an URL) will be, and you should be able to safely scan your data.

Comment: @didierc Oh so my solution of converting to html entities isn't good? I should have just escape the data instead? I'll research more into escaping. Thank you.

Comment: well, the question is, why do you store your html in escaped form? My guess would be that you want to avoid SQL exploit. I think it should be possible to avoid such problems without escaping it, depending on which language and DB bindings you are using. However, you may have other reasons, so I cannot say if escaping is good or not in your case. All I can say is that it would be easier if it were not.

Comment: @MarceloZabani answer is actually a good example of how you can handle it when the html isn't escaped.

Comment: @didierc You are correct. I'll look more into my language, framework, and alternative solutions. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand what you really want. If you want to know, however, how to search for rows in a table that contain the **<** character **efficiently**, you could create an *index on an expression* like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table (position('<' in column));
```

Then you can search for the rows whose desired column contains the pattern by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE position('<' in column) > 0;
```

I assume, of course, that most rows in your table will not contain such a pattern, or otherwise this index wouldn't be of much use.

**NOTICE:**
You could also create an index with the help of the **pg_trgm** module if you are using PostgreSQL >= 9.1. This would also enable you to do other text searches with only one index, and may prove to be much more useful should you need those.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table USING gist (column gist_trgm_ops);
```

Then you can search for your rows like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%<%';
```

For more information, check [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html) in the official docs.

Comment: The problem is I'm storing < character as &lt; (it's html entities representation for data sanitization) in the table and I want to search the table for < instead of &lt;. Is there anyway I can search for < instead of &lt; even though I saved it as &lt; ? Because my DBA does not understand html entities. I was hoping there is some sort of postgresql function for this.

Comment: @mythicalprogrammer My answer does search for < instead of &lt;

Comment: But it's stored in the database as &lt; ? I guess I don't see how searching for < would work when I insert &lt; in the table when I see the < chracter? Unless pg_trgm does something to it (I tried reading it)?

Comment: @mythicalprogrammer that is the aspect of your question I didn't really understand (if you want to look for '<' or for '&lt;'). If you want to search for '&lt;' just replace all appearances of **<** in my answer by **&lt;**